# NullPointerException in my android Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, kotlin-null-safety

I'm new in android and I get this error I can't resolve. Is part of the code for a calculator app and I'm stuck on it.
It gives me a null pointer exception and I don't had trouble with it before I created the listeners and the view variables.

My code program is this:

```
package com.example.calculadora

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        detectarEntrada()
    }

    val button0 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button0)
    val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
    val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
    val button4 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
    val button5 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)
    val button6 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6)
    val button7 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7)
    val button8 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button8)
    val button9 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button9)
    val button_equal = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_equal)
    val button_par_ab = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_par_ab)
    val button_par_cl = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_par_cl)
    val button_coma = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_coma)
    val buttonAC = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAC)
    val button_mul = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_por)
    val button_div = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_div)
    val button_sum = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_sum)
    val button_dif = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_dif)
    val caja = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.caja_de_texto)

    public fun imprimir(simbolo: String) {
        var texto = caja.text.toString()
        var texto_a_poner = texto + simbolo
        caja.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(texto_a_poner)
    }

    public fun detectarEntrada() {
        button0.setOnClickListener { imprimir("0") }
        button1.setOnClickListener { imprimir("1") }
        button2.setOnClickListener { imprimir("2") }
        button3.setOnClickListener { imprimir("3") }
        button4.setOnClickListener { imprimir("4") }
        button5.setOnClickListener { imprimir("5") }
        button6.setOnClickListener { imprimir("6") }
        button7.setOnClickListener { imprimir("7") }
        button8.setOnClickListener { imprimir("8") }
        button9.setOnClickListener { imprimir("9") }
        button_par_ab.setOnClickListener { imprimir("(") }
        button_par_cl.setOnClickListener { imprimir(")") }
        button_coma.setOnClickListener { imprimir(",") }
        button_mul.setOnClickListener { imprimir("*") }
        button_div.setOnClickListener { imprimir("/") }
        button_sum.setOnClickListener { imprimir("+") }
        button_dif.setOnClickListener { imprimir("-") }

        buttonAC.setOnClickListener {
            caja.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("0")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope someone could help me

I searched in the web for similar problems and for this error especially. But I don't know how I could fix it.

Comment: Provide screenshot of error.

Comment: What error was displayed in LogCat?

Comment: @ShivrajsinhSarvaiya Please **do not** request screenshots of anything. OP can simply cut and paste the error message/stack trace from logcat. Please read this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to find out why. OP: please read the help file section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. If you run into an error, you should always post it. It's unlikely that people will try to replicate your entire dev environment to help you. If you want an answer, you have to make helping easier.

Comment: Property initializers are called before `onCreate()`. Before `onCreate()`, you haven't called `setContentView()` yet, so there is no view to find.

Answer (score 2):

All property initializers are called before `onCreate()`, even if you declare them below `onCreate()`. Before `onCreate()`, you haven't called `setContentView()` yet, so there is no view to find. So it throws NullPointerException.

Three ways to fix this:

1. Wrap each `findViewById` call in `by lazy { }` so it won't be initialized before `onCreate()`. For example:

```
val button0: Button by lazy { findViewById(R.id.button0) }
```

2. Make them `lateinit` properties and move the initialization inside `onCreate()`. For example:

```
lateinit val button0: Button
//...

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button0 = findViewById(R.id.button0)
    //...

    detectarEntrada()
}
```

3. Use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). This is recommended, especially when you have so many view properties. It will save you a bunch of repetitious code and will be less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the method `findViewById()` inside the life cycle method `onCreate()` and after `setContentView`.

Also, you can use [ViewBind](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and you can write simple code like
`binding. button0.setOnClickListener { imprimir("0")  }`

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You must call the method `findViewById()` inside method `onCreate()` and after `setContentView`.

For more detail: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

```kotlin
    package com.example.calculadora

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button0 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button0)
        val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        val button4 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
        val button5 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)
        val button6 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6)
        val button7 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button7)
        val button8 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button8)
        val button9 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button9)
        val button_equal = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_equal)
        val button_par_ab = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_par_ab)
        val button_par_cl = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_par_cl)
        val button_coma = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_coma)
        val buttonAC = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonAC)
        val button_mul = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_por)
        val button_div = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_div)
        val button_sum = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_sum)
        val button_dif = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_dif)
        val caja = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.caja_de_texto)

        detectarEntrada()
    }

  

    public fun imprimir(simbolo: String) {
        var texto = caja.text.toString()
        var texto_a_poner = texto + simbolo
        caja.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(texto_a_poner)
    }

    public fun detectarEntrada() {
        button0.setOnClickListener { imprimir("0") }
        button1.setOnClickListener { imprimir("1") }
        button2.setOnClickListener { imprimir("2") }
        button3.setOnClickListener { imprimir("3") }
        button4.setOnClickListener { imprimir("4") }
        button5.setOnClickListener { imprimir("5") }
        button6.setOnClickListener { imprimir("6") }
        button7.setOnClickListener { imprimir("7") }
        button8.setOnClickListener { imprimir("8") }
        button9.setOnClickListener { imprimir("9") }
        button_par_ab.setOnClickListener { imprimir("(") }
        button_par_cl.setOnClickListener { imprimir(")") }
        button_coma.setOnClickListener { imprimir(",") }
        button_mul.setOnClickListener { imprimir("*") }
        button_div.setOnClickListener { imprimir("/") }
        button_sum.setOnClickListener { imprimir("+") }
        button_dif.setOnClickListener { imprimir("-") }

        buttonAC.setOnClickListener {
            caja.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("0")
        }
    }
}
```

You can use View Binding to make your code more readable.

https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=viewbinding&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

you must require to call findViewById in OnCreate Method.

and Google is Recommanded to use ViewBinding so it will save lots of time and Reduce Code make it clean architecture Pattenr.

Only Single Steps for Implementing View Binding

```
  buildFeatures {
            viewBinding = true
        }
```

after Integration Please do coding like below in your activity

```
  private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

binding.button.setOnClickListener { yourLogic() }

    }
```